# CKEditor - get HTML value using jquery val()

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have seen many answers saying to get the CKEditor content using:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
```

However we have been using the following which seems to work:

```
$("#editor1").val()
```

Is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you used [jQuery Adapter](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_jquery.html) which provides jQuery integrations, then both `CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData()` and `$("#editor1").val()` can be used interchangeably, but if you are not using jQuery Adapter then you need to use `CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData()`, as `$("#editor1").val()` will not return the changed content.

Comment: It seems as if there is no difference in the results between the two, even without using the adapter. Can you give an example of how they would differ?